BabylonJS with variant launch not loading
I have cloned this repository: https://github.com/Variant3d/launch-examples/tree/main/babylonJS
And am trying to get it to work. It should work just like this page: https://demos.launchar.app/babylonJS/
So I set up CloudFlare to SSL tunnel so I could serve it on https, then when I tried running the application, it is stuck on loading. The first page is good, but when I click OPEN in the top right, it just is stuck on a spinning wheel and times out after 30 seconds. See here in images:


Any idea why this would get stuck and wouldn't load the BabylonJS page? Also I edited main.js including console.log("MAIN JS at least CALLED") and it doesn't appear to get logged in the console. Is the main.js in the src file being loaded?
